# Can't pass complex -style to clang-format when invoking from Scala

Tags: scala, shell, command-line-arguments

In Scala, I invoke command-line `clang-format` as follows:

```
val formatterParams = List("-i", "-sort-includes", s"-style=llvm", headerFile.getAbsolutePath)
Process("clang-format", formatterParams).!
```

This works fine. From command line I can invoke it as

```
clang-format -style='{BasedOnStyle: llvm, IndentWidth: 4}' library-api/src/main/resources/Cols.hpp
```

This also works fine. So I write

```
val formatterParams = List("-i", "-sort-includes", "-style='{BasedOnStyle: llvm, IndentWidth: 4}'", headerFile.getAbsolutePath)
Process("clang-format", formatterParams).!
```

and... get

> Invalid value for -style, using LLVM style.

I've tried to pass the entire command to `Process.apply` as well, but it doesn't help.

EDIT: Using the Java `ProcessBuilder` does work as a workaround. I'd still like an answer for Scala `Process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the single-quotes around the value for the `-style` argument.

These single quotes are special Bash syntax you need on the command line to stop Bash from interpreting the braces which are also special Bash syntax.  Bash removes the single quotes from the final value of the argument when invoking `clang-format`.

But `Process` doesn't use Bash to run the subprocess, so the single-quotes get forwarded to `clang-format` itself which probably doesn't understand them.